TestCafe expect text to equal one of the following
I'm writing a test where if the user clicks a button, there should only be 2 scenarios (texts) that could happen.
For example
await t
    .click('button')
    .expect(Selector('div#result').textContent)
    .eql('My text A')
    // or 'My text B' ??

How can I test this in TestCafe?

First you await the user clicks the button, then save the textContent in a variable, and inside expect you can check on both conditions with or operator ||, if false it will output the message inside the ok.
test('Button click results in one of two texts', async t => {
    await t.click('button');
    
    const textContent = await Selector('div#result').textContent;

    await t.expect(textContent === 'My text A' || textContent === 'My text B')
        .ok('Wrong text.');
});


Thanks! Is the .ok() necessary?

@Nermin, yes it is necessary for this situation, because .expect() method on its own does not perform any checks, it requires an assertion method like ok to test the condition.
